# Error: Invalid Swift Support when uploading a build to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, swift

I'm submitting my first build for TestFlight distribution and am getting the following error. Bitcode is turned off. Other answers seem decently old so figured I'd re-ask for 2018.

> Invalid Swift Support - The files libswiftDarwin.dylib, libswiftMetal.dylib, libswiftCoreAudio.dylib, libswiftsimd.dylib, libswiftQuartzCore.dylib, libswiftos.dylib, libswiftObjectiveC.dylib, libswiftDispatch.dylib, libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib, libswiftCoreFoundation.dylib, libswiftUIKit.dylib, libswiftCoreMedia.dylib, libswiftAVFoundation.dylib, libswiftCore.dylib, libswiftFoundation.dylib, libswiftCoreImage.dylib aren’t at the expected location /Payload/MyApp.app/Frameworks. Move the file to the expected location, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it.

I have a .dylib file that I compile for my project that lives at `./MyProj/Core/lib.dylib`. I saw this browsing around as well

> It's likely you have a plain dylib outside of a framework somewhere, which is only supported on macOS. Please review the Troubleshooting section of Tech Note 2435 for more context.
>
> If having a bare dylib is indeed the cause of the problem, please file a bug for an error message that clearly explains this.

Comment: Seems like all the information you need is there in the error message

Comment: The bit I'm confused about is what to do with my dylib file. Do I need to convert it into a framework and import it?

Comment: Check the build options for that framework, it's possible that it needs to include the swift std libs. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1881/_index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here was to add a new target to my project, the first Framework option that Apple gives and to move the `.dylib` file and the `interface.h` file into it. Link the `interface.h` file into my `framework.h` file, import the framework into my main target

Happy to give more info (it's a longer answer) if anyone needs it. Just leave a comment.

Comment: I would love a step by step explanation. I have been trying your approach for days but I keep getting a linker error `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Have you seen this?

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING

Search for "Embedded .dylib Files"

I would try to follow that steps, It should work.

Comment: If my answer is correct then mark as correct please :)

Comment: Thanks!! You saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have the 'Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries' at its default setting in your main target and possible other targets (extensions).
Also make sure you don't archive Release version with a Debug setting (Scheme).

Answer (score 0):

1.In XCode 10.1, Apple has introduced new architecture for Arm64e used in A12 chipset.

2.The App Store and TestFlight don't accept submissions containing arm64e.

To remove Arm64e from swiftlib run below script, Please note that change path inside script file.

https://github.com/ndpiparava/Swift_StripArm64e